# Drawing graticule with GDAL/OGR?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, ogr, grids-graticules

I'm trying to generate a graticule with user-defined range of latitude, longitude, and interval; however, my code only displays one line of latitude and one line of longitude when loading it in QGIS. How do I create a grid of lines of latitude and longitude?

```
multiline = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbMultiLineString):
for lon in range(min_lon, max_lon, interval):
    line1 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    lat = min_long + interval
    line1.AddPoint(min_lon, lat)
    line1.AddPoint(max_lon, lat)
    multiline.AddGeometry(line1)

for lat in range(min_lat, max_lat, interval):
    line2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
    lat = min_lat + interval
    line2.AddPoint(lon, min_lat)
    line2.AddPoint(lon, max_lat)
    multiline.AddGeometry(line2)

print(multiline.ExportToWkt())
with open ('multiline.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(multiline.ExportToWkt())
```

Comment: Why are you adding the interval before adding a point to the line? When you're building the longitude lines, you need to minimally add points at the min and max _latitude_ values and vice versa.

Comment: I've been doing trial and error on the script but I don't have lines between the min lon and min lat

Comment: You're only seeing one line because of this `lat = min_long + interval`. You are getting the same value of `lat` every pass of the loop because the `interval` value doesn't change.

Comment: Also, when you loop through the longitude values, shouldn't you be creating latitude lines? and vice versa

Answer (score -1):

There is an built-in plugin to create grids:

`Vector` -> `Research Tools` -> `Create grid`

[image: Create Grid]

There you will find a variety of options, depending on what vector type (*Point, Line, Rectangle, Diamond, Hexagon*) and CRS (geographic or projected) you select:

[image]

The plugin is explained [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_creation_tools/creategrid.html).

Comment: I'm trying to write a script that creates a WKT output file containing graticule instead